# Nginx try_files for multiple directories

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have static files in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/public and /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/static that I want nginx to check in. IE. domain.com/photo.png could be in either the public or static directories.

This is my nginx configuration but with the try_files like, my entire website gives the nginx 500 internal server error. Without this line, my nodejs express app loads fine but no static files are accessible of course. What do I have wrong?

```
location ~ / {
    root /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/app;
    try_files /public/$uri /static/$uri;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

Comment: Do you intend to use this for both reverse-proxy and serving the files?
 Also, please paste the output of `nginx -t` if you are on linux

Comment: Yes I do. Output of nginx -t:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Answer (score 0):

First you should tell us what backend `localhost:3000` does:

1. It is used as fallback when file not found at both `/static` and `/public` locations;
2. Or it is used as HTTP API to handle user requests with certain URLs, methods and so on.

In both cases you should split your configuration into two different locations.

In first case you should use `try_files` with `proxy_pass` as fallback.

```
location / {
    root /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/app;
    try_files /public/$uri /static/$uri @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

In second case you should split locations by URL, something like that

```
location / {
    root /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/app;
    try_files /public/$uri /static/$uri @fallback;
}

location /api {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```